# Syntax for comparing when supporting IComparable

Tags: c#, class, generics, icomparable

See code below.
There is a squigley red line under first > second
Operator cannot be applied to operands OBJ and OBJ.

Is there some easy way to do what is intended here?

```
public static OBJ Swap<OBJ>(ref OBJ first, ref OBJ second) where OBJ : IComparable
{
    OBJ temp = first;
    OBJ temp2 = second;
    second = temp;
    first = temp2;
    if (first > second) return first else return second;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the `CompareTo` method?

Comment: You should consult the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.icomparable

Comment: Whatever class OBJ is placeholder for, that class should support CompareTo.  Should operator > work then, seemlessly.  Why is it a syntax problem?

Comment: The `IComparable` interface does not enforce the implementation of the comparison operators, just the `CompareTo` method. Use that instead.

Comment: @Kam How does the compiler know that's possible? All you've done is state that the class should implement `IComparable`.

Comment: @Kam Operator implementation is independent of IComparable.CompareTo implementation. There is no enforced connection between both and it’s a just a general guideline to implement the operators when also implementing the IComparable interface. But it’s not a must and the results of the operators and CompareTo can also be different - although this is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (first.CompareTo(second) > 0) return first else return second;
```

Comment: you don't have to do like this for int and other types.  if (i > j) works because int supports IComparable.  So I thought that was the norm.  Not sure why it is this way.  Still, I will accept as answer, shortly.  Just leaving room for comments. 
 Thanks

Comment: Like I wrote in my comment above: integer i > j does not work because it implements IComparable, but because it implements the > operator.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting that compile-time error is that the only restriction you've placed on the type is that it implements `IComparable`, the only method that interface guarantees is the `CompareTo` method, and not all types implement the comparison operators.

Since [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2) is guaranteed to be available, however, you can use that instead.

Also note that you should use the null conditional operator ([`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)) when calling the `CompareTo` method, since there's the possibility that `first` is `null` (in which case, calling `.CompareTo` will throw an `ArgumentNullException`).

The rest of your code can also be slightly simplified. First, you can shorten it slightly by using the ternary operator ([`?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)) when deciding which item to return. And second, in a swap operation you only need a single `temp` variable to hold the value of the first variable you re-assign. For example:

```
public static T Swap<T>(ref T first, ref T second) where T : IComparable
{
    var temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;

    return first?.CompareTo(second) > 0 ? first : second;
}
```

Here's a case where the `null` value would otherwise throw an exception, but with the code above it works as expected:

```
string first = null;
string second = "2";

string largest = Swap(ref first, ref second);
```

Answer (score 1):

> If (i > j) works because int supports IComparable.

Nope. This is incorrect. It works because it implements [comparison operators](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/10/11/c-comparison-operator-overloading-and-spaceship-operator/). For example:

```
public static bool operator >(MyClass l, MyClass r) {
    return l.Value > r.Value;
}
```

This is unrelated to [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2) which requires that a single *instance method* be defined in implementing classes:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) {
```

It is entirely possible to create a class what implements IComparable without comparison operators, or vice versa.

All you are saying with `public static OBJ Swap<OBJ>(ref OBJ first, ref OBJ second) where OBJ : IComparable` is that OBJ should implement `IComparable` - there is nothing implied that the type passed here will have comparison operators defined. Because of this, the compiler can't allow you to perform equality comparisons on objects that may not have comparison operators defined.

I know you're thinking "but the compiler can work out what I've passed at compile time", but remember that your compiled application (even in .exe form) could be referenced by an external application which could pass an invalid type.

You should instead use `CompareTo`:

```
return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
```